# Loading properites file using

Tags: java, sql-server-2005

Please look at the following code for a MSSQL Server 2005.

**Properties File**

```
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=LibMgmtSys
user=sa
password=passwrod
```

**Connection File**

```
public class DBConnection {

    static Properties dbproperties;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        InputStream dbInputStream = null;
        dbInputStream = DBConnection.class.getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties");

        try {
            dbproperties.load(dbInputStream);
            Class.forName(dbproperties.getProperty("driver"));
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbproperties.getProperty("url"),
                    dbproperties.getProperty("user"),
                    dbproperties.getProperty("password"));
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println("error : " + exp);
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

The above code gives me a NullPointException when I try to do dbproperties.load(dbInputStream).  Am I doing something wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't instantiate `dbproperties`, so it's null when you try to dereference it (`dbproperties.load(dbInputStream);`). Change it to:

```
    try {
        dbproperties = new Properties();
        dbproperties.load(dbInputStream);
```

Comment: LOL.  That was simple.  Thanks.